# How many days can I stay in Peru as a tourist?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, spain, visa-free-entry, peru, spanish-citizens

Next year I am going to travel to Peru from Spain. I need to know how many days I can stay in this country as a tourist. I have already looked at some websites, but some of them say the maximum is 90 days, while others say 183 days.

Apart from that, I have seen this [page](http://busquedas.elperuano.com.pe/normaslegales/decreto-legislativo-de-migraciones-decreto-legislativo-n-1350-1471551-2/) with a new law.

Comment: Do you need a visa for peru? Or are you visa exempt? Are you a Spanish citizen?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=es&DE=pe&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of Spain for a maximum
>   stay of 90 days. [...] Nationals of Spain are allowed to stay for a maximum of 90 days during any 6 months.

So from the date of the first entry, from that date your time in Peru during the next 6 months cannot exceed 3 months. If it does, you need a residence permit.

183 days used to be the period for citizens of most countries, but has been abolished for Schengen citizens.